# Rust Deserialization Lifetimes Problem : 'de must outlive 'a

Tags: rust, lifetime, serde

I have the following two structs for which I derive serde traits.

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Item<'a> {
  pub id: &'a str,
  pub name: &'a str
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Set<'a> {
  items: Vec<Item<'a>>
}
```

When I try to compile this, I am getting am getting the following error message to ensure that lifetime parameter `'de` from `Deserialize` needs to outlife lifetime parameter `'a`:

```
15 |     #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
   |                         ----------- lifetime `'de` defined here
16 |     struct Set<'a> {
   |                -- lifetime `'a` defined here
17 |         sets: Vec<Item<'a>>
   |         ^^^^ requires that `'de` must outlive `'a`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'de: 'a`
```

But when I add the required bound as follows, I am getting an error message that `'de` is not used.

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Item<'a> {
  pub id: &'a str,
  pub name: &'a str
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Set<'a, 'de: 'a> {
  items: Vec<Item<'a>>
}
```

```
16 |     struct Set<'a, 'de: 'a> {
   |                    ^^^ unused parameter
   |
   = help: consider removing `'de`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `PhantomData`
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add [`#[serde(borrow)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#borrow) to the `sets` field:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Set<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    items: Vec<Item<'a>>,
}
```

This will bound the `'de` lifetime in the generated code on `'a`. Note that this happens implicitly for fields of type `&str` or `&[u8]`, but for anything else you need to expicitly request the trait bound.

Comment: Jinx, you're right your answer is better.